# display the view behind tableView (or scrollView)

Tags: ios, scrollview, tableview

For example:
there is a tableView, when it is pulled down, the back view display. the effect is like this:

[image]

I tried like this but not working:

```
[self.view addSubview:logoView];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Comment: :Really I cant understand wt you asking.. Can you say briefly about your problem

Comment: @TamilKing You want him to still brief his question further? Are you serious?

Comment: @TamilKing when a tableView pulled down, there would display another view below it, not at the top of it.

Comment: @Veelian:Change your logo view frame below the tableview height.

Comment: Set your tableView background colour to clear colour. Don't clear your tableviewcell background colour. Now the view should be visible. Let me know if this helps .... You do need to play around with your logo view.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda I tried, the logo view can be saw directly through tableView.

Comment: @TamilKing I know what you mean, but I want the logo view behind the tableView,just like two layers, so that logo view would not move when tableView moved.

Comment: @Veelian:You set the tableView background as your logoview. Keep your UITableviewCell as what color you want..

Comment: @TamilKing Yes it works and thanks,but the logo view would be saw directly when there is no data in the talbeView.

Comment: @Veelian:I post my answer if it was useful accept it..

Comment: @Veelian:Check the tableArray has no data. set the TableView backGround as whitecolor..

Answer (score 1):

You have to

1. add your logo image view below the table view in xib.
2. set table view background color to clear color
3. Set logo image hidden.
4. in `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate` or check for your self which delegate is best suited. set the logo image hidden to **NO**

Answer (score 1):

You set the tableView background as your logoview. Keep your UITableviewCell as what color you want.

Comment: the problem is :if there is no data in tableView, the logoview can be saw directly through tableView, I want the logo view to be covered by tableView until tableView is pulled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i recognize your problem but i think you want something like this:

you'll have to use:

```
[self.view insertSubview:aboveSubview: ];
[self.view  insertSubview:belowSubview: ];
```

not
    [self.view addSubview: ];

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same as the example image above by adding the view with a negative y offset.

```
UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.tableView addSubview:header];
```

However if you have content in this view, such as a logo, it will appear to be pulled down from the top, rather than behind the table, I don't know if this is the effect you want or not.

Comment: This would add the header at the top of tableView, and the header would move with the tableView.